# What is the difference between 0..size and 0...size in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading some ruby code, and see `0..size` and `0...size` are used in similar situations.

Are there any difference, or they are just identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`..` (two dots) means that ju want an inclusive range. `...` (three dots) means that you want a range but ommit the last element. Example:

`0..5` returns `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

`0...5` returns `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`

Answer (score 5):

Quite simple actually. `..` includes the ending value in the range (so `2..5` is 2,3,4,5) and `...` excludes it (so `2..5` is 2,3,4). Nothing more to it.

Answer (score 1):

`..` creates an inclusive `Range`, `...` creates a Range object where the right limit is excluded.

```
(0..5).to_a
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

(0...5).to_a
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```